# Vuex Getter not pulling data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

I have a vuex store that I am pulling data from into a component.  When the page loads the first time, everything behaves as expected. Yay.

When I refresh the page data is wiped from the store as expected and pulled again into the store as designed.  I have verified this is the case monitoring the state using Vuex dev tools.  My getter however doesn't pull the data this time into the component.  I have tried so many things, read the documentation, etc and I am stuck.

Currently I am thinking it might be an issue with the argument?...

If I change the argument in the getter, 'this.id' to an actual value (leaving the dispatch alone - no changes there), the getter pulls the data from the store.  So it seems the prop, this.id has the correct data as the dispatch statement works just fine.  So why then wouldn't the getter work?

this.id source - The header includes a search for the person and passes the id of the person that is selected as the id prop.  example data: playerId: 60

Thoughts?  Appreciate any help.

This code works on initial page load, but not on page refresh.

```
  props: ["id"],
  methods: {
    fetchStats() {
      this.$store.dispatch("player/fetchPlayer", this.id).then(() => {
        // alert(this.id);
        this.player = this.$store.getters["player/getPlayerById"](this.id);
        this.loading = false;
      });
    }
  },
```

This code (only changing this.id to '6' on getter) works both on initial load and page refresh.

```
  props: ["id"],
  methods: {
    fetchStats() {
      this.$store.dispatch("player/fetchPlayer", this.id).then(() => {
        // alert(this.id);
        this.player = this.$store.getters["player/getPlayerById"](6);
        this.loading = false;
      });
    }
  },
```

Here is the getPlayerById getter:

```
  getPlayerById: state => id => {
    return state.players.find(plr => plr.playerId === id);
  },
```

Here is the fetchPlayer action:

```
export const actions = {
  fetchPlayer({ state, commit, getters }, id) {
    //   If the player being searched for is already in players array, no other data to get, exit
    if (getters.getIndexByPlayerId(id) != -1) {
      return;
    }

    // If the promise is set another request is already getting the data.  return the first requests promise and exit
    if (state.promise) {
      return state.promise;
    }

    //We need to fetch data on current player
    var promise = EventService.getPlayer(id)
      .then(response => {
        commit("ADD_PLAYER", response.data);
        commit("CLEAR_PROMISE", null);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("There was an error:", error.response);
        commit("CLEAR_PROMISE", null);
      });

    //While data is being async gathered via Axios we set this so that subsequent requests will exit above before trying to fetch data multiple times
    commit("SET_PROMISE", promise);

    return promise;
  }
};
```

and mutations:

```
export const mutations = {
  ADD_PLAYER(state, player) {
    state.players.push(player[0]);
  },
  SET_PROMISE(state, data) {
    state.promise = data;
  },
  CLEAR_PROMISE(state, data) {
    state.promise = data;
  }
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchStats()` ?

Comment: Can you provide the `getPlayerById` getter source? Maybe `this.id` is a string and your getter is doing a === comparison against a number.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You have problems with specific place of the app but didn't show it.

Comment: 2 questions, where do you get the this.id from and how is the "player/fetchPlayer" action implemented? Note that in order to .then after dispatch works correctly you've got to return a Promise. The only way to let the calling function (initiator of action) to know that an action is complete - is by returning a Promise and resolving it later

Comment: Where are you calling fetchStats()?  fetchStats can be called from the created lifecycle hook or I also watch $route.params to see if the id param changes.  If so, fetchStats() is called.

Comment: Added getPlayerByID getter, and the player/fetchPlayer action to the post.

Comment: Where does this.id come from?  The header includes a search for the person and passes the id of the person that is sleeted and the id prop.  example data: playerId: 60

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask.  I was trying to make it easier on you, but made it more difficult.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It's not uncommon, writing a proper question requires to know half the answer. As said, a reasonable explanation is that `id` is string and you compare it with a number. You can start with making id prop `type: Number`, this should result in a warning in console

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask.  Verified that on refresh prop comes through as a string instead of a number.  This gets me moving.  Thanks.